# na(series) == 0 condition

Tags: c#, pine-script

I have this code right here:

```
basis = sma(srcsr, lengthsr)
devsr = mult * atr(lengthsr)
uppersr = basis + devsr
lowersr = basis - devsr
bbr = (srcsr - lowersr) / (uppersr - lowersr)
bbe = ema(bbr, maLen)
up = bbe[1] > bbe and bbe[2] < bbe[1] ? bbe : na
bt = bbe[1] < bbe and bbe[2] > bbe[1] ? bbe : na

highest_1 = highest(3)
topH = na(up) == 0 ? highest_1 : na
lowest_1 = lowest(3)
bottomL = na(bt) == 0 ? lowest_1 : na

tf = fixnan(topH)
bf = fixnan(bottomL)
```

And I would like to convert it in c# but I cannot understand the part na(up)==0 ? ... and the fixnan.

Comment: Which part? the na? (Not a number) or (whatever == 0 ? WhateverEqualsZero: WhateverIsNotZero)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not quite correct using of the `na()` function. `na()` returns `bool`, so for comparision it's result to integer, the `integer` is casted to `bool`, so it acts like:

`na(up) == false ? ...`

But you may change it to just

`not na(up) ? ...`

More about pine's typesystem is here: https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Type_System